# Rails 4.1: Square and Stripe integrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, payment-processing, square

We are using Square card readers as a POS. However square doesnt allow our customers to save credit cards. We have a subscription model and ability to save credit card is imp.

So we are thinking about using Stripe for online usage (Stripe doesnt have POS).

We need a way to make Stripe and POS (Square) behave well. Is there a Gem/library we can use? Here are few thing we are looking for:

1] Save customer info across Square and Stripe. 
2] Use same discount codes for both Square and Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you don't allow credit card numbers to come into your system, or you will come under PCI rules.

You might be able to do this using both Square's and Stripe's API libraries. Collect the data in your form and then feed it into their respective APIs. Square's API [does not support payment processing](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq/), but you might be able to submit the customer information.

One possible workflow would be:

1. Collect subscriber/customer data in a form on your site.
2. When the form is submitted, use stripe.js to submit the credit card data to Stripe.
3. Receive the Stripe token from the JS response, and insert it into a hidden form field.
4. Submit the from and then send the customer data through the Square Ruby API.

Sauce:

- https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js
- https://connect.squareup.com/
- https://github.com/nov/square
- https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#endpointnames

Comment: Yes, Most likely I will have to do some API munging. Was hoping I find a Gem or library especially to manage discount codes, subscription cycles etc between the two.